# Grails getting size 0 for domain class hasMany elements

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Here is my pool domain class:

```
class Pool {
    //Can be account id or name dependent on input csv format
    String poolName
    static hasMany = [accountToFollow:AccountToFollow]
    static constraints = {
        poolName nullable: false,unique: true
        accountToFollow nullable: true
    }
}
```

Here is how I retreive the `accountToFollow` for a particular pool

```
def poolInstance = Pool.findByPoolName("First Pool")
int count = Integer.parseInt(params.numHandlesToFollow)
println "AccountToFollow: ${poolInstance.accountToFollow.size()}"
```

There are over 50K accountToFollow in the database(confirmed via listing the accountToFollow when editing the "First Pool" and checking database).
Why do I get 0?

Comment: what does def count = poolInstance.accountToFollow.size() return ?

Comment: @vahid it returns 0 as in question

Comment: could it be because `accountToFollow` is lazily loaded? maybe do a search via `AccountToFollow` domain class - `AccountToFollow.findAllByPool(poolInstance).size()`?